# Launch Atlas composer generation from command line

Tags: qgis, print-composer, batch, atlas

I am using QGIS 2.2 and have configured a composer with atlas generation. I would like to launch this atlas generation every day. 
The idea is to write a batch and launch it with a cron.

Is it possible to launch atlas generation from command line ?