# QGIS atlas generation - batch process for many atlases

Tags: qgis, pdf, batch, atlas

I have many different QGIS projects, each one is designed to create one particular atlas or map book in pdf format (one different book per every QGIS project).
Month by month I must actualize each atlas, so I have to open each QGIS project and generate the corresponding pdf book. Because this process take a lot of productive time I want to find a way to actualize those atlases in a quick way, so my question is:
Is there a way to create a batch so the pdf actualization process can be automated?

Comment: Have you looked at how Python can be used to script the process? Try to figure out how to run your atlas generation with python. Then add an iteration with relevant variables (month name) and run it.

Comment: related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98158/qgis-launch-atlas-composer-generation-from-command-line?rq=1 (unanswered)

Comment: Mmm no I have not. I never used python code or console writting, but I believe i could handle it. Have you a link to acces more information about how to do it? I will really appreciate your help.