# Can I export all print composers at the same time?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, batch

I have quite few different print composers. Can I somehow export them to pdf, one pdf for each composer,  at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "[Maps Printer](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MapsPrinter/)" plugin, or the "[multiprint](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/multiPrint/)" plugin which has this functionality.

To take it even further, you can export multiple print composers from multiple .qgs files using the method from "[Batch export from multiple QGS projects to image or PDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/207307/1297)" which uses pyqgis and Maps Printer.

For example, using Maps Printer:

Open the Maps Printer window from **Plugins > Maps Printer > Export multiple print composers**

[image: opening Maps Printer plugin from QGIS]

Then set your options as needed like selecting an output folder, the print composers to export and output file type. Click **Export** when ready.

[image: setting Map Printer plugin options in QGIS]

Comment: For those like me who don't read documentation - in current versions of Maps Printer, the way to access the functionality of the Maps Printer plugin is through the Processing toolbox and not the Plugins menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to use PyQGIS, then the following code snippet will export all Print Layouts to PDF - just substitute your preferred directory in place of `C:/temp/`:

```
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
for layout in manager.printLayouts():
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    exporter.exportToPdf("C:/temp/{}.pdf".format(layout.name()),
        QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

Ref: https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-exporting-layouts/